# Python - property returns old value when inheriting from abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is about inherited class resolution order. This is a dummy code snippet illustrating my issue:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 1
        self.set_value()

    @abstractmethod
    def set_value(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def set_value(self):
        self.__value = 2

dc = DerivedClass()
print(dc._DerivedClass__value)
print(dc.value)
assert dc.value == 2
```

Code output:

```
2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 26, in <module>
AssertionError
```

I expected the `DerivedClass` to override the `set_value` method before it is called in `__init__`. However, this is not the case as the property somehow remembers the original `.__value` value and not the new one. Can someone explain me why this is happening?

What is a good solution in this case? My real case is a rather large base class with inherited classes overriding only key methods - like `.set_value` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you used double-underscore name-mangling, `self.__value`. This prevents subclasses from being be able to override `__value`, That is **its only purpose**.

If you want to fix it, use the conventional *single* underscore:

```
self._value
```

Comment: @George it happens. But you should ask yourself why you used double-underscore name-mangling in the first place. It is *not the same thing as private*, python doesn't *have private variables*. Don't use it willy-nilly like you would `private` in, say, Java. It is very specifically for preventing accidental name-collisions in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the `DerivedClass` to override the `set_value` method before it is called in `__init__`.

Yes, this is actually happening. The `set_value()` called in the constructor is the one from `DerivedClass`.

> this is not the case as the property somehow remembers the original `.__value` value and not the new one.

No, what is happening here is that you have **two** separate variables. Even though both are named the same (`__value`), they are actually different, separate variables.

That's how private variables (those starting with two underscores and ending in fewer than two underscores) behave in Python.

The way this is implemented is that Python will mangle their names. In fact, you're exploiting that yourself in the first `print()` statement, looking at `_DerivedClass__value`.

You could rewrite this code in your mind where all references to `__value` from the code inside `BaseClass` actually read `_BaseClass__value` and you'll clearly see what is happening.

Since the `value` property is defined in `BaseClass`, so it will **always return `_BaseClass__value`.**

You're setting `_DerivedClass__value` on the `DerivedClass`, but there's no way to access it.

> What is a good solution in this case?

Don't use private variables. They tend to create this kind of confusion. Use protected variables instead, such as `self._value`, as they can be accessed just fine from derived classes (no name mangling happens there.)

If you can't do that, then assume you can't touch the private variables from the subclass (since, in effect, you actually can't!) and go through the exposed accessors such as `set,_value()` in this case.

If you want to modify the behavior of the `set_value()` method in the subclass, then use `super()` to access the implementation of the base class when you want to set the actual value (since writing to `self.__value` won't work, as you noticed.)

Comment: *python doesn't have private variables*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private I agree that they're not really private and just name mangling. But you could argue the same in C++, you can access a private member with pointer manipulation if you know what to do... In any case, "private variable" is the terminology Python itself uses and I don't see any reason not to follow it.

Comment: No, from your own link: "“Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python." and "Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling." The term used is *name-mangling*.